# How do I get this Trinket code to run in standard Python?

Tags: python

I was doing this simple exercise for fun regarding the physics behind a projectile motion. I wanted to graph it based on a theoretical model of acceleration, velocity, and displacement. I actually found this exercise in [Trinket](https://rhettallain_gmail_com.trinket.io/physics-python-for-mere-mortals#/beginning-numerical-calculations/projectile-motion) however I would like to apply it on Spyder 4 instead. I know Trinket uses some different commands from normal python 3, and I am relatively new to python programming (or programming in general), so I can't figure it out.

Here's my code from Trinket:

```
thegraph=graph(xtitle="x position [m]", ytitle="y position [m]")
f1=gcurve(color=color.blue)

#starting position (x and y)
#you can change the starting position to whatever you like
x=0 #m
y=1.5 #m

#intial velocity
v0=7 #m/s
theta=30*pi/180 #this is converted to radians

#the startin x and y velocities
vx=v0*cos(theta)
vy=v0*sin(theta)

#gravitational constant
g=9.8 #N/kg
#mass - this doesn't matter, but I put it in anyway
m=.1 #kg

#starting time and time step
t=0 #sec
dt=0.01 #sec

#the loop run as long as the vertical position is >= to zero (the ground)
while y>=0:
  #calculate the force in the y-direction
  Fy=-m*g 
  #calculate the acceleration in the y-direction
  ay=Fy/m

  #update y velocity (use acceleration)
  vy=vy+ay*dt

  #update x and y position
  x=x+vx*dt
  y=y+vy*dt

  #update time 
  t=t+dt


  #plot x and y to get trajectory - you can change this
  f1.plot(x,y)

#print out stuff
print("final x position = ", x, " m")
print("time of flight = ", t, " s")
```

On Spyder, the error code is this:

```
NameError: name 'graph' is not defined
```

Comment: What is the result when you try to run the code in spyder? Wrong output, no output, error message? Please [edit] to include  this information

Comment: Trinket uses a modified version of Python I think. I don't know if they are specific packages or what, but the code just doesn't work on Spyder because it's not standard python. I can add the error message, however it doesn't work because there are some commands that are not defined. In fact, what I was wondering is how to make it applicable in Spyder.

For example, I don't think ```
thegraph=graph(xtitle="x position [m]", ytitle="y position [m]")
f1=gcurve(color=color.blue)
``` is defined.

Comment: What is graph? An import? A custom class? That is the issue it seems like but we have no idea how it was declared.

Comment: As I said I am quite new in programming. I know it did work on their website, however they did not use any of the classical packages for graphing like NumPy or pandas. Or maybe they are automatically declared in the background? I have no idea. Honestly, how they did it on their website is quite irrelevant, I just wanna be able to do it on Spyder. I just posted my code so that you know what sort of think I wanna graph, and you can check their website for more insight. https://rhettallain_gmail_com.trinket.io/physics-python-for-mere-mortals#/beginning-numerical-calculations/projectile-motion

Comment: It looks like everything else is valid python except the plotting, which makes things easier. The most used plotting library is [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). What type of plot are you trying to create? It may be worthwhile to have a look at the mtplotlib documentation and see if you can figure out the basics of what you're trying to accomplish and ask specific questions if you get stuck

Comment: it may be as simple (to start with) as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at the top of your script, remove `thegraph=...` and `f1=...`then at the end replace `f1.plot(...` with `plt.plot(...)`

Comment: I get another error code:
NameError: name pi is not defined.
Do I need to import another package?

Comment: yes, `import math` library

Comment: @G.Anderson not quite that simple because the `f1.plot(...)` line is *inside* the loop, so it's adding pairs of `x` and `y` to the plot point-by-point.

Comment: @APhillips and then use `math.pi`, `math.sin` and `math.cos`.